# Character matching and replacing in a string column of dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a string column in a pandas dataframe that is sometimes followed by '>>@>'. I want to remove this across the entire column, only when this string appears at the end.
Example:

| Original column | Expected column |
| --- | --- |
| Hi Joe >>@> | Hi Joe |
| Hi Mark | Hi Mark |
| >>@>Hi Anna | >>@>Hi Anna |
| >>@>Hi Tid >>@> | >>@>Hi Tid |

Is there a way to remove the specific string only from the end of each cell for the entire column in one go?

Comment: `df['Expected column'] = df['Original column'].str.rstrip('>>@>')`?

Comment: @AnuragDabas - Here working, but `Hi Joe @>>@>` remove `@>>@` - so rather not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$` for specified end of string with `\s+` for match space before `>>@>`:

```
df['Expected column'] = df['Original column'].replace('\s+>>@>$', '', regex=True)
print (df)
   Original column Expected column
0      Hi Joe >>@>          Hi Joe
1          Hi Mark         Hi Mark
2      >>@>Hi Anna     >>@>Hi Anna
3  >>@>Hi Tid >>@>      >>@>Hi Tid
```

Seems working also:

```
df['Expected column'] = df['Original column'].str.rstrip('>@')
```

But it remove all last `>@` values, so generally failed.

it means if string ends by `aaa >@@@>>@>>@>` all values are removed - output is `aaa`